# Issue with a pointer to a SDL_Rect class member using an abstract base class

Tags: c++, polymorphism, sdl

I have an abstract base class with a few inheritors, and I made an array of pointers of the abstract base class that will point at inheritors:

abstract base class:

```
class Tile              
{
    public:

        bool isPassable;
        void setTileSet( SDL_Texture *Texture );

        SDL_Rect* clip;

};
```

inheritor:

```
class Floor: public Tile
{
    public:

        bool isPassable = true;
        SDL_Rect clip = { 20, 0, 20, 20 };

};
```

pointer array:

```
Tile * dungeon[ z ][ x ][ y ] = {{{ nullptr }}};
```

When I try to access the member SDL_Rect clip through the pointer array to blit a tile, nothing happens. The program compiles and runs but the screen remains default black:

```
dungeon[ 0 ][ 0 ][ 0 ] = &floor;

Draw::renderTexture( TILESET, REN, 0, 0, dungeon[ 0 ][ 0 ][ 0 ]->clip );
```

However, when I just use the class Floor to access clip, the image will blit fine:

```
Draw::renderTexture( TILESET, REN, 0, 0, floor.clip );
```

I thought that the pointer abstract base class may have been not loading, but when I tried to word the code to weed it out:

```
SDL_Rect error = { 0, 0, 20, 20 };

if( dungeon[ 0 ][ 0 ][ 0 ] != nullptr )
{
    Draw::renderTexture( TILESET, REN, 0, 0, dungeon[ 0 ][ 0 ][ 0 ]->clip );   
}
else
{
    Draw::renderTexture( TILESET, REN, 0, 0, &error );                          
}
```

the screen remains black.

This is the Draw::renderTexture function, although I doubt it is the problem:

```
void Draw::renderTexture(SDL_Texture *texture, SDL_Renderer *render, int x, int y, SDL_Rect *clipping )     
{

SDL_Rect destination;
destination.x = x;
destination.y = y;
destination.w = clipping->w;
destination.h = clipping->h;

SDL_RenderCopy( render, texture, clipping, &destination );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In every Floor, you have two versions of isPassable:  `Floor::isPassable` and `Tile::isPassable`.  One is initialized and the other is not.  You also have two versions of clip.  `Floor::clip` is uninitialized and `Tile::clip` is not.  So naturally when you refer to your dungeon element as a Tile, it accesses the uninitialized one and disaster strikes.

The code you have that says `if( dungeon[ 0 ][ 0 ][ 0 ] != nullptr )...` doesn't help, because `Tile::clip` isn't null; it's uninitialized.

The solution is to eliminate isPassable and clip from either Tile or Floor, so you'll have only one copy of each, and can't access the wrong one.

If you want to keep it in Tile, these are the things to fix:

- initialize them, maybe defaulting to false and NULL, inside Tile's ctor -- all members of all classes need to be initialized.  That's why your if statement didn't help
- have Floor's ctor call Tile's ctor, passing it appropriate values, if Floors need different initial values:  `Floor () : Tile (true, 20, 0, 20, 20) {}`, perhaps.

Comment: I was under the assumption that I was supposed to access the Floor::clip through the abstract base classes Tile::clip? How would I point to a member of the inheriting classes without the base classes having a copy of the member?

Comment: Whether it should be a member of Tile or Floor depends on whether Tile needs these members.  If it does, then it should have them, and Floor inherits them.  
  
The way you refer to an inherited member is just to refer to it:  `dungeon[ 0 ][ 0 ][ 0 ]->clip`, for example.  This refers to the member `clip`, whether it's inherited or not.

Comment: We can also discuss whether you should make those members private or protected, but to keep it simple, I suggest you just:  make these members a copy of Tile; remove them from Floor; initialize them as needed in the appropriate ctor; and see how that goes.

Comment: Thanks! You've been very helpful and clear to a noob like me :)

Comment: I take it that's working for you.  Great!

If your question is answered -- by *this* answer -- please click to accept.  If it's answered, but by another answer, please click to accept that one.

Comment: Well, I thought it would, but I have only occasional access to the internet for the next few weeks. Once I get a steady connection I will be sure to upvote the comment once I can test your solution fully! :)

Comment: Okay, it works! Thanks so much - I clicked the check mark beside your answer. The trick was the ctor, I simply misunderstood classes and inheritance I guess! Thanks for teaching me haha.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast your array member first so that it knows which member it is looking at. Currently you have an array of `Tile` instances so when you pass `dungeon[ 0 ][ 0 ][ 0 ]->clip` to the render function, the system assumes you mean the base class.

If you change it to `(Floor*)(dungeon[ 0 ][ 0 ][ 0 ])->clip` it should work.

However I would point out that this looks like a very poor design, possibly because you haven't fully understood inheritance and polymorphism, although you may have some reason for doing it the way you have.

I would personally change the classes to be as follows, first the base class:

```
class Tile              
{
    public:
        Tile() :
            m_passable(true) {}
        Tile(bool passable, SDL_Rect& clip) :
            m_passable(passable),
            m_clip(clip) {}

        virtual ~Tile() {}

        inline void SetTileSet(SDL_Texture *texture) { m_texture = texture; }
        inline SDL_Texture* GetTileSet() { return m_texture; }

        inline void SetClip(SDL_Rect& clip) { m_clip = clip; }
        inline SDL_Rect& GetClip() { return m_clip; }

        inline void SetPassable(bool passable) { m_passable = passable; } 
        inline bool IsPassable() { return m_passable; }

    protected:  
        bool m_passable;
        SDL_Rect m_clip;
        SDL_Texture* m_texture;

    private:
        Tile(Tile const&) = delete;
        Tile& operator=(Tile const&) = delete;
};
```

and then the inheriting class:

```
class Floor : public Tile
{
    public:
        Floor(bool passable, SDL_Rect& clip) :
            Tile(passable, clip);

    protected:
    private:
        Floor(Floor const&) = delete;
        Floor& operator=(Floor const&) = delete;
};
```

Then when you want a new `Floor` instance just do:

```
SDL_Rect clip = { 0, 0, 20, 20 };
Floor* myFloor = new Floor(true, clip);
```

Then put it in to your array simply by doing:

```
dungeon[ 0 ][ 0 ][ 0 ] = (Tile*)myFloor;
```

Finally if you make these changes, you should pass by reference to your rendering function:

```
void Draw::renderTexture(SDL_Texture* texture, SDL_Renderer* render, int x, int y, SDL_Rect& clipping )     
{

    SDL_Rect destination = { x, y, clipping.w, clipping.h };
    SDL_RenderCopy( render, texture, &clipping, &destination );
}
```